# Insert Row when 2 conditions are met

Tags: excel, vba

I have created below code which works like IF `Col"B"` any cell `<> ""` And `Col"L"` any cell `= "Leop"` then add row below to the active cell.

I mean I'm trying to achieve is to insert single row after certain row which contain in column B any value, and if column L in same row contains value = "Leop". Then add the row after that certain row.

But an error is appear. `Compile Error: Invalid use of property` on `xlDown`

Your help will be appreciated to fix it.

From this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

```
Sub firstcondition()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim p As Long
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim datt As Variant
    Dim IRow As Long
    
    Set ws = Thisworkbooks.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    With ws
    LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("B2:B" & LRow)
    Set rng2 = .Range("L2:L" & LRow)
    
    dat = rng
    datt = rng2
    IRow = Selection.Row
    
    For i = LBound(dat, 1) To UBound(dat, 1)
    For p = LBound(datt, 1) To UBound(datt, 1)
    
        If dat(i, 1) <> "" And datt(p, 1) = "Leop" Then
        Rows(IRow + 1).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift: xlDown
        End If
    
End Sub
```

It will be like in formula:

```
IF(AND(B2<>"",L2="Leop"),"InsertRowBelow to Row 2 If condition is met","")
```

and will drag it down to the lastRow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thisworkbooks.Sheets("Sheet2")` should be `Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")` and missing `=` in `Selection.Insert Shift:= xlDown`

Inserting or deleting rows will change the last row number so start at the bottom and work upwards.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub firstcondition()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, LRow As Long, r As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    With ws
        LRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For r = LRow To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(r, "B") <> "" And .Cells(r, "L") = "Leop" Then
                .Rows(r + 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox n & " rows inserted", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you @CDP1802 Yeah i also see my mistakes. Thanks for highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with autofilter, you dont have to loop through each row. So it will work faster for larger data.

```
Option Explicit
Sub firstcondition()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long, cl As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    LRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("L1:L" & LRow).AutoFilter 1, "Leop"
    
    For Each cl In ws.Range("_FilterDatabase").SpecialCells(12).Cells
        If ws.Range("B" & cl.Row) <> "" Then
            cl.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Use this only if you are not already using autofilter elsewhere in the same sheet.

Comment: Yeah this approach is well. But already filters are being used. Thanks